# Как сделать inject в Base класс?

Tags: android, dagger2, dagger

Даггер принимает в метод `inject(Вью)`, но если это Base класс, то я в целом могу ему передать вью его наследника, но что делать если мне нужно сделать `inject()` и в наследнике тоже. Получается как бы два инжекта на одно и то же вью один из Base один из наследника...

Как правильно сделать такую имплементацию?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger2 генерирует на основании метода `inject` реализацию, в зависимости от того, что это за класс, то есть если для базового класса эта реализация будет одна, а для наследников другие. 
Например у базового класса `Base` есть одна зависимость (общая для всех):

```
@Inject
A a;
```

А у наследника `BaseChild` есть ещё какая-то зависимость:

```
@Inject
B b;
```

В таком случае для метода `inject(Base base)` сгенерируется реализация, которая устанавливает только поле `a`, и если в этот метод передать объект наследника `BaseChild`, поле `b` у него окажется непроинициализировано.

Comment: вот смотрите есть Base и поле `a` чтоб проинициализировать это поле я делаю `inject(this)` (но `this` в данном случае будет baseChild() так как он наследник) в `onCreate()` таким образом получаю эту инициализацию, потом  идем по иерархии попадаем в `BaseChild()` класс и тут есть поле `b` которое я тоже инициализирую в `onCreate()` методом `inject(this)` и тут опять `this` это тот же самый `baseChild` который я передал ему в `Base`, верно?

Comment: Да, всё верно .

Comment: Но я не могу в 2х разных местах передавать одно и тоже вью для инжекта.